# How to minimise a quantity using a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms

I'm somewhat new to Genetic Algorithms and I've been exploring the use of them to minimize a quantity (Y), where my optimum value is a small negative value.

I've implemented an algorithm that has a population of N initial candidates. Where each candidate is a set of parameters, $\theta$, where I seek to find the optimal set $\theta^{*}$, such that,

$$ argmin \ Y = f_{\theta}(X)$$

I perform the Genetic Algorithm in this manner,

1. Initialize N candidates sets of $\theta$
2. Calculate the fitness value, Y, for each candidate $\theta$
3. Assign a probability value for each value of Y such that a low value in Y corresponds to a large probability, p.
4. Select 2 candidates in proportion to their probability values, p.
5. Perform crossover (i.e. mix the parameters of the 2 initial candidates and create 2 new proposed candidates)
6. x% of the time, perform mutation where the parameters of a proposed candidate are slightly altered by random noise.
7. repeat steps 4) to 6) until an entirely new population has been generated.
8. repeat steps 2) to 7) for G generations (or until convergence to a solution).

The problems that I have in my solution is

1. Finding an adequate function which defines an appropriate p for a given Y
2. The diversity in the population dies off quite quickly. For example, at the first generation (i.e. G=1) I have 100 unique values for 100 candidates for Y. Within 5 generations it reduces to around 25 unique values and by G=30, it collapses to just 1 solution for all candidates.

In regards to problem 1) I've tried numerous functions that convert a given value of Y to p, e.g.,

$$p(Y) = (Y-Y_{max})/(Y_{max}-Y_{min})$$

$$p(Y) = ln(1 + exp(-Y))$$

I've even merged the two above, and still, this problem persists. And secondly, are there any good techniques on maintaining some variability within my set of candidates besides mutation (or in addition?). I've tried varying the mutation rate from 0 to 100% and this doesn't improve the results at all.

I have looked at the probability values for all values of Y as the algorithm evolves and I have noticed that some candidates have 0% (effectively killing off that solution). So, I assume there's some relation between this probability function and my set of candidates losing variability.

Thanks in advance!